# DataBinding - loadImage() occurs App crash using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations, android-databinding

I am making a sample Android app of RecyclerView + DataBinding + Kotlin.

When I create annotation binding method of 'imageUrl' app crashes.

I made same source project using Java.
And there was no problem.

Only using Kotlin occurs error.

## RecyclerView item layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="index" type="int"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.retrofitktex.viewmodel.DataVM"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.books[index].imageURL}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

## Annotation binding method of 'imageUrl'

```
    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("bind:imageUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
            // source code
        }
    }
```

## build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    ~
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14'
    kapt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

## build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Let me know what I missed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bind` from declaration of bindingAdapter fun .
Do it like :

```
companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
        fun loadImage(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String?) {
            // source code
        }
    }
```

and inside xml:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.books[index].imageURL}"/>
```

P.S: also make sure `viewModel.books[index]` does not return `null`